# Weekly calendar navigation in angular 8

Tags: jquery, angular, calendar

[image]

I'm new to angular and I have to make calendar weekly in a horizontal list view. When  loading the page current week should display and it will call API and display the task details. When we click on the previous week or next week, it will call another Api and it will display the last week/next week task details respectively.
I am currently using the full calendar for achieving this.How can i get the current week and how can I call the API to display the data? When i change this the week, how can i change the corresponding task details?
I have attached a screenshot that should show what I'm going to do. 
 Anyone can help me out this situation.

```
ngOnInit() {
  setTimeout(()=> {
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar( {
      header: {
        center: 'month,week' // buttons for switching between views
          }
      , views: {
        week: {
          type: 'agenda', duration: {
            days: 7
              }
          , buttonText: 'week'
            }
      }
    }
    , 100);
 }
```

I have referred the below link for the fullCalendar  installation in angular
https://therichpost.com/how-to-implement-fullcalendar-in-angular-8/

Thanks,
Sara.

Comment: That's not a good article to follow. You don't need `jQuery` because manipulating DOM directly in Angular is not recommended. Use this package https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink

Comment: Thanks Maihan. I will try to use the recommended package and see if i can make it as per my requirement.

Comment: I managed to add the angular calendar. But is there any way we can remove the hours listing after the week listing? I tried but not able to do it. I need the week display, with next and previous week and according to the date , i need to call an API and list the data from the database. Not sure i will be able to achieve this using this calendar. If any help , or suggestion will be a great  help to me.

Comment: Hi Can any help  me out to get the week dates when clicked on previous and next button?

Comment: The question is too broad and needs lots of work to provide a solution. Look at the documentation and API section of the package. Try something and open another question if you stuck with something.

Comment: Sure Maihan. I  will open up a new question.